# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} (1+\sin x)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this problem :

Calculate :

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} (1+\sin x)^{1/\sqrt{x}}$$

I don't really know to approach this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming knowledge of elementary limits, why would you *not* think its 1?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I do think its $1$ but I don't really know how to "show" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick for handling limits that involve exponents is to take logs. Specifically:
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Define }L&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1+\sin x)^{1/\sqrt{x}}\\
\log L &= \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log (1+\sin x)}{\sqrt{x}}\\
(y=\sqrt{x})\qquad&= \lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\log (1+\sin y^2)}{y}\\
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\log(1+z)=z+o(z)$ and $\sin(z)=z+o(z)$, it follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
\log L &= \lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y^2+o(y^2)}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0^+}y+o(y)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence $L=1$.

EDIT: Had a mistake earlier.

Comment: I assume you meant $\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln(1+\sin x)}{\sqrt x}$

Comment: I don't understand why this is true $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1+\sin x)^{1/\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log (1+\sin x)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$$, Can you please explain?

Comment: @JaVaPG It's not true. What Lucian said is correct.

Comment: I had a mistake while typing it... should be fixed now.

Comment: And why is this true? $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1+\sin x)^{1/\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{\ln(1+\sin x)}{\sqrt x}$$

Comment: You need a "ln" on the left hand side. It's true because $\ln x$ is a continuous function, so you can move it inside the limit and apply property of logs to pull out the exponent.

Comment: @pre-kidney I don't really understand your explanation, I understand that $lnx$ is continuous, but why can you move it inside the limit? can you please explain?

Comment: @JaVaPG I think your doubt can be satisfied if we understand why, for $\;a>0\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ we have $$a^x=e^{x\log a}$$ which can be easily verified applying basic rules of logarithms. From here, that $$\left(1+\sin x\right)^{1/\sqrt x}=e^{\frac{\log(1+\sin x)}{\sqrt x}}$$ so you can calculate the limit in the exponent and then, *using continuity* of the exponential function, you can calculate the limit easily.

Comment: @Timbuc Thank you, now its clear just one little thing if I may, can you explain why $$\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\log (1+\sin y^2)}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y^2+o(y^2)}{y}$$

Comment: @JaVaPG Do you know about Taylor series or power series of functions? This is what pre-kidney is using where he writes "Since..." : the power series for $\;\log(1+x)\;$ around zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $y = (1 + \sin(x))^{1/\sqrt{x}}$ so that $\ln(y) = \frac{\ln{(1+ \sin(x))}}{\sqrt{x}}$ by using the property $\ln(a^x) = x\ln(a)$ (which is true for all logarithmic functions, not just ln). Here, you can take the limit as $x \to 0^+$, and then exponente both sides to get the desired limit.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f(x)=(1+\sin x)^\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \cdot\ln{(1+\sin x)}}$ but since $\ln(1+\sin x) \cdot\frac{1}{\sin x} \to 1 $ as $x \to 0^+$ then $f(x)=e^{\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x} \cdot \sin x} \cdot\ln{(1+\sin x)}} \to e^0=1$ because $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x} \cdot\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$